# What is the origin of the word "мешок"?

Tags: этимология

What is the origin of the word мешок?

Comment: a hint - google "мешок этимология"

Answer (score 11):

Мешки used were made of skins with the fur.The word мешок comes from the word мех

Comment: I think references should be provided for this answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

[Откупщиков "К истокам слова"](http://flibusta.is/b/219475/read)

Что такое мешок?

Не менее важную роль играет также и анализ тех формальных средств (например, приставок, суффиксов), с помощью которых образовано слово (словообразовательный анализ). Допустим, что мы хотим выяснить, каково было происхождение слова мешок. Выделяем в этом слове суффикс — ок (-ек). Находим ряд русских слов с тем же самым суффиксом, которые с полной очевидностью соотносятся с простыми бессуффиксными образованиями: смешок — смех, грешок — грех, душок — дух, пушок — пух и т. п. Если в этот же самый словообразовательный ряд включить слово мешок, то его можно будет легко соотнести со словом мех. Таким образом, словообразовательный анализ позволил нам прояснить этимологию слова. мешок (буквально: ‘маленький мех’). Правда, здесь, быть может, последует возражение: кто же изготовляет мешки из меха?! Чтобы ответить на этот вопрос, обратимся к истории. В древности «мешки» (мехи) изготовляли из шкур животных. В этих мехах обычно держали вино и другие продукты. Известно, например, выражение из Евангелия: «Не вливают вина молодого в мехи ветхие». Древние ассирийские воины переправлялись через широкие реки вплавь с полным вооружением, пользуясь при этом надутыми воздухом мехами (мешками из шкур). Этот способ переправы был знаком и другим народам древности. Ещё шире, по-видимому, было распространено хранение в мехах вина и других жидкостей. Да и в наши дни такие мехи для хранения жидкости употребляются многими народами Востока. По-русски такой мешок, изготовленный из цельной шкуры, называется бурдюком (это слово было заимствовано из азербайджанского языка).